# Viewing datastore in Google App Engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb

I used the endpoints library to create an api, but now i want to check if objects are being populated correctly. I am using python ndb. I start the application using GoogleAppEngineLauncher but i am not able to view the datastore at "/_ah/admin/datastore" on my localhost .

Currently my app.yaml looks like this :

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: service.APPLICATION

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name:endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

What handlers do i need to add in the app.yaml, also do i have to start the datastore separately or 
does the GoogleAppEngineLauncher starts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datastore is automatically started with the development server.

With the latest version of App Engine, you should see something like this in the logs :

```
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:30,851 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:32,344 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Update check failed: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
WARNING  2014-09-07 17:36:32,404 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images
API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:32,523 api_server.py:171] Starting API server at: http://localhost:62276
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:32,530 dispatcher.py:183] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:32,536 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
```

The last line indicates how to access the admin console :

```
INFO     2014-09-07 17:36:32,536 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at:
http://localhost:8000
```

Comment: Oh..thnks ..i wasn't checking for it at the admin port.